# How to create the object literal method to use the http get request to get the json data?

Tags: html, json, angularjs, get

I got stuck with  the http get method which is used to  get  the json data.
The http get method is working fine it  is actually  fetching the json data, but I'm not able to connect it with the object literal.

To explain clearly  here is the piece of code where I'm stuck.

```
   var x ={};
  $http.get('chart.json') //reading the studentRecord.json file
         .success 
       (function(data1){
       //alert(data1);
 $scope.x = data1;

       }); 

  var conversionChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'funnel',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: "100%",
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: x

 });
```

I'm trying to apply  the http.get method to the `dataSource:`to fetch the json data to it but,  its not  working. And my  main task is to  apply  the http.get request to the `dataSource:`which  makes my  code work  properly.

And let  me give you the entire piece of code to  understand better.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>FusionCharts - Funnel 3D Chart</title>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">

      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script> 
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.widgets.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>







</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <!-- A funnel 3D Chart showing a conversion analysis in percentage of visiting to purchase in Harry's Supermart website last year 

Attribute :
# showPercentValues - set to 1 to show the values in percentage.

-->

<div id="chart-container" ng-controller="ParentCtrl"  ng-init='load()' ng-model="dataSource1">FusionCharts will render here</div>

</body>


</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


//The below code will read the data from student.json file and will pass to the $scope variable 
 myApp.controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope, $http)
  {   

 $scope.load = function(){
     //alert("2");
    FusionCharts.ready(function () {
      //alert("1");
   var conversionChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'funnel',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: "100%",
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource : function(){



      $http.get('chart.json') //reading the studentRecord.json file
            .success 
        (function(data1){
        alert(data1);
       $scope.dataSource = data1;// binding the data to the $scope variable
 }); 

        }

   });



conversionChart.render();

});

};
});
```

**chart.json**

```
{ 

            "chart": {
                        "caption": "Ensource sales report",
                        "subcaption": "Purchase - Conversion analysis for last year",
                        "decimals": "1",
                        "isHollow": "0",
                        "isSliced": "1",
                        "labelDistance": "15",
                        "plotTooltext": "Success : $percentOfPrevValue",
                        "theme": "fint",
                        "baseFontSize":"18"
            },
                "data": 
                [

                                        {
                                            "label": "Total",
                                            "value": "385634"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "Contacts",
                                            "value": "175631"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "Leads",
                                            "value": "84564"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "Sanctioned",
                                            "value": "35654"
                                        },
                                         {
                                            "label": "Disbursed",
                                            "value": "12342"
                                        }

            ]





}
```

My main intention is to use the http.get method to  fetch the json data to

```
dataSource :
```

Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/HUKvROQv8wIiFfx6uZBk?p=preview

I'll be very thankfull if somebody help me with this .Plz help me because I'm new bee to  angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your plunker, the code should be:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []); 


//The below code will read the data from student.json file and will pass to the $scope variable 
myApp.controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope, $http) 
{ 

$scope.load = function(){ 
//alert("2"); 
FusionCharts.ready(function () { 
//alert("1"); 
var conversionChart; 
$http.get('chart.json') //reading the studentRecord.json file 
.success 
(function(data1){ 
//alert(data1); 
$scope.dataSource = data1;// binding the data to the $scope variable 
conversionChart = new FusionCharts({ 
type: 'funnel', 
renderAt: 'chart-container', 
width: "100%", 
dataFormat: 'json', 
dataSource : $scope.dataSource 

}); 



conversionChart.render(); 

}); 

}); 

}; 
});
```

Comment: @ Mindastic it is actually  getting invalid data when i try  to  insert  the http.get  request in it

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Also, what about "data1" does it return something?

Comment: i have made some changes to my code i vl  edit the question so, that u  can understand it

Comment: @ Mindastic i have tried my  best  to  some go step forward have i  have changed piece of code where i got stuck ..

Comment: But the problem is that your data doesn't exist until it gets a reply from the http.get request. Did you try in the way i showed in my response. It is calling the server and then, when it gets a reply, it creates the chart.

Comment: var x ={};
   $http.get('chart.json') //reading the studentRecord.json file
     .success 
     (function(data1){
     //alert(data1);
     $scope.x = data1;
  
     }); 
       
      var conversionChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'funnel',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: "100%",
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: x
        
   });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82830/discussion-between-anil-chean-and-mindastic).

Comment: The answer was edited to the version that is currently working.